# Check if value is in dropdown list and disable it in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-attributes

How can i check if an item is in a select drop down list and disable it if it fulfills some condition?

Thanks in advance!

BTW i tried the following and nothing is happening

```
$('#select-box option').each(function() 
    {if (this.val() == item) 
       {$('#select-box option').attr("disabled","disabled");}});
```

***EDITED****

The second code i used while debugging. It went through smoothly until i did the comparison with item. I am wondering if it is because of the this value. If so how do i overcome it?

```
function checkSelectBox(item){ <!--alert(item);-->
                               $('#SCOPE option').each(function()
                                 {
                                   if($(this).val()==item)
                                   { alert('Camein')
                                   $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                                     return false;    
                                    }

                                 });
                             }
```

Comment: submit the code which you've tried with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
$('#yourSelectId option').each(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == 'some_value_to_check') {
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: yes this looks like something i want. Let me try it out! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hey this is working example: http://jsfiddle.net/R6GAr/11/

**HTML: Sample**

```
<SELECT NAME="SCOPE" id="SCOPE">  
 <OPTION VALUE="G"> Global
 <OPTION VALUE="D" selected="selected"> Dynamic  
</SELECT>​
```

**JQuery: sample**

```
 $('#SCOPE').change(function(){

    if($(this).val() == 'G') {
      // **disables the option here with attr as below**
      $('#SCOPE option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').attr("disabled","disabled");

      // **Now you want that disable to be not selectable as well, this line does that.**
      $('#SCOPE option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').attr("selected",false);
  }


});
```

Hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: they are all good answers! thanks guys but i think i need to debug somemore

Comment: No worries, I have a working demo attached if you want to debug! **remember** you will need attr(select, false) as I mentioned above. cheers!

Comment: i think i know what is the problem. Apparently i can't use this to compare. i'll show the code in an answer below.